Fan always on and cannot suspend
I have Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on a Lenovo ideaPad 3 laptop. OS updated a few days ago .
Since that update , the fan is always running , at low speed but still.
And suspend won't work. Only the screen will switch off but the system in general seems to be fully running , and the fan too.
How do i diagnose this? Or i could just wait for the next update if it's likely to be fixed.
EDIT:
cat /sys/power/mem_sleep
[s2idle]


Can you add the output of cat /sys/power/mem_sleep in your question??

@Ajay added now

You should change it to s2idle [deep] for system to go suspend properly. Also, make sure your BIOS->config->power-sleep state is correct (or whatever it is called). It should be set to Linux. Default is probably windows. Not having this set properly can block you from setting [deep]

@ajay How do you access these settings?
Lenovo IdeaPad 3 BIOS configuration settings are brief and do not include these settings.

@A.Gh. repeatedly press the "F2" key when you turn on your computer, right after the Lenovo logo appears; depending on your keyboard configuration, you may need to press "Fn+F2".

This I know. But the BIOS doesn't have any power related controls where I can change the sleep state. From what I read elsewhere, I was under the impression there was an advanced mode, that maybe you were referring to. But this seems to me now to be a legend. I'm amazed at how limited the BIOS settings are!
